# A Number Theory problem based on selection of sequences

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-number-theory

> Take any 37 integers from the set $\{1,2,3,...112\}$, then show
> that there will always exist two integers out of those 37 integers
> such that $(x-y)\in\{9,10,19\}$

Here is my approach: Let the set of 37 numbers chosen be S. If we include any natural number n in set S we cannot include $n\pm9, n\pm10, n\pm19$ in the set S, that is if all these values are still within the set $\{1,2,3,...,112\}$. I am unable to rigorously prove that we cannot chose 37 numbers with the previous condition.

Can anybody please provide a rigorous proof for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that because you are removing $n\pm 9,10,19$, then for every choice of $n$ you are also eliminating the possibility of choosing atleast 3 other numbers. So, if you choose 37 numbers, there are at least $3*37$ other numbers that cannot be included in this set. Since 37*4>112, you cannot choose 37 numbers satisfying this property from a set of 112 numbers.

Comment: You are missing out a key fact. You do not eliminate the possibility of choosing 3 numbers for every number you choose. For example, if you include 1 in the set S, then you cannot include 10,11 or 20. Say you choose the next number as 2. This implies that we cannot choose 11,12 or 21. Notice that 11 has already been taken care of by choosing 1. Hence, we get only 2 eliminations by choosing 2, not 3.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ignore my comment.